# .htaccess subdomain redirect + wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I enable this:

If I type: `maggew.com/abcxyz` 
you'll get redirected to `mr.maggew.com/abcxyz`

If I type: `maggew.com/privacy`
you'll get redirected to `mr.maggew.com/privacy`

if I type: `maggew.com/refund`
you'll get redirected to `mr.maggew.com/refund`

If I type: `maggew.com/contact`
you'll get redirected to `mr.maggew.com/contact`

etc..etc...etc....

*I was using Shared Hosting on 1&1, and now I have a digital ocean droplet.

I tried to use [HTACCESS REDIRECT GENERATOR](http://www.htaccessredirect.com/) but didn't have much luck.*

**Here is my current .htaccess:**

```
# REDIRECTS STORE
redirect 301 /shop http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /market http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /outlet http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /bazaar http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /boutique http://mr.maggew.com/store

# PROTECT WP-CONFIG.PHP
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

#force subdomain of mr.maggew.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mr\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://mr.maggew.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: tried to add a rewrite cond where u check the entered domain? then redirect to your new url with 301 [L]

Comment: i just don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: the two answers bellow is what i wanted to say, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

```
before you do all the folder specific redirects you need to redirect the domain first
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www\.domain.com\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Option 2**

if you have old url instances in your content you can use something like this to update to the new one. I'm not sure how effective this is.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-update-urls-when-moving-your-wordpress-site/

**Option 3**

or you can use http://wp-cli.org/ modify database instances or you can use mysql command line search and replace.

all of your urls from content and page referencing urls are stored in the database. you can do a mass search and replace if you know what you're doing.

Comment: When I copy / pasted your chunk of code from option 1 (excluding your "before you do all...") to the top of my .htaccess file, I didn't have any luck. For example,  when I typed maggew.com/training it didn't redirect to mr.maggew.com/training -- I'm gonna try option 2 and 3 right now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on the same host and directory structure, you can add a condition checking for the subdomain in the HTTP_HOST, if the subdomain is missing you can redirect to it.

```
# REDIRECTS STORE
redirect 301 /shop http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /market http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /outlet http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /bazaar http://mr.maggew.com/store
redirect 301 /boutique http://mr.maggew.com/store

# PROTECT WP-CONFIG.PHP
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
#force subdomain of mr.maggew.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mr\.
RewriteRule /?(.*)$ http://mr.maggew.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Alternative

```
#force subdomain of mr.maggew.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mr\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://mr.maggew.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I added your snippet of code to the top of my .htaccess file, and it didn't redirect. For example, if I type in maggew.com/training it redirects to the homepage, not mr.maggew.com/training

Comment: that looks correct. try this very simple code: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maggew\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mr.maggew.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I just pasted your update code and made my .htaccess file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/9z7sbpw4 -- Also, I opened up a private tab in Chrome to double-test check and still no luck. I'm gonna try to add unixmiah into the file and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried to add you second chunk of code and make this: http://pastebin.com/yJgVERWi but didn't have any luck neither (even with private tab). When I tried to type maggew.com/contact I was redirected to mr.maggew.com

Comment: I just tried adding your chunk of code into the .htaccess file @unixmiah and I had no luck...this is what I made: http://pastebin.com/PxxZ8mMu

Comment: Thanks for helping me with updates and investing your time @fyrye - I replaced my .htaccess with this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/rPSS1Y8H and I'm not having luck redirecting maggew.com/privacy to mr.maggew.com/privacy

Comment: @MaggewDotCom Updated using your pastebin by adding rewrite rule after wordpress rules

Comment: When I copy / pasted your updated response code @fyrye - I was not able to see results. For example, when I type maggew.com/refund i'm not redirected to mr.maggew.com/refund but instead, redirected to mr.maggew.com

Comment: @MaggewDotCom Try the alternative please

Comment: Your persistence is like none other! Sadly, it doesn't work. I updated my original question code too @fyrye

Comment: @MaggewDotCom Temporarily disable all your custom non-essential plugins (especially any that have to do with cache or security), check your WP Admin General Settings, and ensure your site address and wordpress address have been updated to to the new URL.

Comment: @MaggewDotCom All my tests with the snippets I gave work on my wordpress site with a standard wordpress config, including, landing pages, nested subcategories, and wp-admin. I did have to move the redirect above wordpress redirects. I updated the answer to demonstrate my tests.

Comment: I didn't have any luck, my WPMU environment must be shot. Thanks for the effort but I'm going to tackle this another time.

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions not working in 2023, so I do research on it.

In my case, you can use...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://new-domain.com/$1  [L,R=301,NC]
```

Read full details at https://www.arnlweb.com/forums/web-development/what-is-htaccess-redirection-how-to-use-it